# HTML5 Server-Sent Events via cURL

Tags: php, html, curl, server-sent-events

I'm trying to make an HTML5-based notification system, based on when something occurs on a table in my database. I have specifically made the table for this notification feature . This is how it works:

1. Server-Sent Events page (`sse.html`) will refer to `source.php` for its notification content.
2. `action.php` contains the action that would trigger  a change of content notification by inserting data in to a table.
3. `source.php` will periodically check for any new data in table. It should pass a notification if there's any.

My question is it possible if to do this without checking the table?

I'm thinking of using cURL to directly send content to `source.php` when the action in `action.php` is performed. Can this be done?

I've seen cURL used with the HTTP header `Content-Type` set to `text/event-stream`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

**`sse.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<body>  
  <script>  
    var source = new EventSource('source.php');  
    source.onmessage = function(event){  
      var text = event.data;  
      window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('', 'Alert', text).show();  
    }  
  </script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

**`source.php`**

```
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");

mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
mysql_select_db("eventstream");

$q = mysql_query("select textnotif from notification where read='0'");
$r = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$notif = $r[textnotif];

if($notif != ""){  
    echo "data: ".$notif.PHP_EOL;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

> ... is it possible if to do this without checking the table?

No.

Your PHP script *has* to check the SQL table to see if any data has changed. The only way PHP can check for a database change is to query the database.

Comment: It's worth adding that there are better ways to do this, such as pub/sub using a message queue. You should take a look at this video: http://vimeo.com/20605470